# Disable Form submit button if text field filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to implement some Jquery that basically says "If this text field is filled in then disable the submit button so that the form cannot be delivered/submitted"

So far I have come up with this, but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$this = $("#inputValue");
 if($this.val().length>0){ 
$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 }  
});
```

When i fill in the form and include text within the field I am not supposed to the form still gets submitted, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: My experience says that it should be vice versa: if the text field is *empty*, then the submit button is disabled.

Comment: not required here, the filed is hidden so if it is populated by a bot for example then i dont want the form submitted

Comment: That still doesn't really make sense.  Usually the point of including a hidden form field is to use to to transmit _some_ value with the form.  Are you sure you want to it be completely empty?  If so, then why even have it in the first place?

Comment: yes thats why i have put if length>0, or is that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only runs once on runtime. After that, it doesn't get checked again.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#inputValue").on('change', function (){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Or, as @thomasfedb suggested:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#inputValue').on('change', function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', $(this).val().length > 0);
  });
});
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to extend this to re-enable to submit button when the input is empty.

Comment: It would be neater to do `$('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled", $(this).val().length > 0)`.

Comment: Had a typo, @thomasfedb fixed it, try again please

Comment: have re tried, still sends me mail, its not validating that the field a length greater than 0

Comment: Have you tried both solutions? If so, please create a JSFiddle to recreate the issue that you're having.

Comment: Waiting for a JSFiddle then ;)

Comment: Your button is not an `<input>`. It is a button. http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenvisser101/SnMt2/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to bind a [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event to do the check every time when user enters something to `#inputValue` field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputValue").on("keyup", function() {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", !!$.trim(this.value).length);
    }).trigger("keyup");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `hidden` field it might be better to bind the `change` event:

```
$('#inputValue').on('change', function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', this.value.length > 0);
}).change();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, though i can still send emails, so not working

Answer (score -2):

Try using this code.

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: You haven't actually addressed the question asked.